# arrange numbers in order

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone show me an easy way to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Problem: Arrange the numbers $a= 2^{88}, b= 3^{55}, c= 5^{44}, d= 7^{33}$ in order form least to greatest.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $2^8=256$, $3^5=243$, $5^4=625$, and $7^3=343$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can take the $11^{\text{th}}$ root of each, and compare $2^8,3^5,5^4,7^3$.  These are all small enough to compute by hand without much trouble, or you might know them.  Clearly $5^4 \gt 4^4 = 2^8$, but I don't see anything else obvious.